# Python: Write a program to find the time period(s) of the largest price drop(s)

Tags: python

i am suppose to solve this question but i am stuck.

Write a program to find the time period(s) of the largest price drop(s) when a list of price(s) is given. For instance, if the list is [300,301,303,299,300,298,301,305], then there is one period of the largest price drop: from time 2 with price 303 to time 5 with price 298.

Below is my solution but there is a flaw

```
def maxdrop(p):
  high = low = drop = newhigh = 0
  for i in range(len(p)):
    if p[i] >= p[high]:
      newhigh = i # invariant: p[high] <= p[newhigh]
    else: # so: p[i] < p[high] <= p[newhigh]
      newdrop = p[newhigh] - p[i]
      if newdrop >= drop:
        high, low, drop = newhigh, i, newdrop
  return ((high, p[high]), (low, p[low]), drop)
def test():
  p = [20,22,19,20,24,18,21,24,27]
  print p, maxdrop(p)
  p = list(reversed(p))
  print p, maxdrop(p)
  if __name__ == "__main__":
  test()
```

If you try with the below list
[2,1,2,3,4,3,2]

the sharpest drop should occurs over 4,3,2 – the last 3 elements.
But with my code, the output is 2,1 – the first 2 elements.

Please assist, thanks!

Comment: you'll get much better results with properly formatted code. Also if this is homework, be advised that some people will want you to use the [homework] tag. You should use the edit button to fix the formatting and deal with the tagging.

Comment: @user: Please add proper indentation.

Comment: can you please explain 'largest drop' in more detail? is time range an issue? is the slope an issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. This is not a homework, but an extra problem inside my notes i trying to solve myself.

By Largest Drop, i mean the largest continuous drop.
E.G. p = [20,22,19,20,24,18,17,24,27]:
Largest drop should be from 24 > 18 > 17, which is a 7pt drop.

Comment: Just being a nit about the indentation.  Most python is written with 4 spaces (or tabs), not 2 spaces.  ;)  See PEP8, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: real sorry, i copied from terminal and all the indention when haywire. thats y i manually changed it. Thanks all for the replies and assistances. i shall try one by one and update this post for those that work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my try at it. It works correctly on all the examples that you gave.

I basically just go through the array and when there is a drop between two points, referring to the first point as A, look ahead until there is a value that is higher than A. I keep track of the minimum in this region. If the difference between A and the minimum is a bigger drop than what I've already found, I hold onto it. I then start looking again for a drop between two points, starting at the next point that was higher than A.

Here's the code. It isn't very Python-esque, but it works pretty well (I'd just go to Cython if I needed it to be faster). Also, it returns the magnitude of the drop.

```
def maxdrop(p):
    bestdrop = 0
    wheredrop = -1,-1
    i = 0
    while i < len(p) - 1:
        if p[i+1] < p[i]:
            bestlocal = p[i+1]
            wherelocal = i+1
            j = i + 1
            while j < len(p) - 1 and p[j + 1] < p[i]:
                j += 1
                if p[j] < bestlocal:
                    bestlocal = p[j]
                    wherelocal = j
            if p[i] - bestlocal > bestdrop:
                bestdrop = p[i] - bestlocal
                wheredrop = i, wherelocal
            i = j+1
        else:
            i += 1
    return bestdrop,wheredrop
```

A big problem with your code is that you only look at the next value for the biggest drop after a new high value is found.

Comment: Thanks!! i think this works, gotta try more.. this kinda like what i am changing to.

Answer (score 5):

You want the maximum sum contiguous sequence, but inverted. [This page](http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-maximum-subsequence-problem) has the best explanation of it I have seen.

The basic algorithm will look like this:

```
>>> def min_sum_subsequence(seq):
...     minsofar = 0
...     minendinghere = 0
...     for s in seq:
...         # invariant: maxendinghere and maxsofar are accurate
...         # are accurate up to s
...         minendinghere = min(minendinghere + s, 0)
...         minsofar = min(minsofar, minendinghere)
...     return minsofar
... 
>>> series = [300,301,303,299,300,298,301,305]
>>> returns = [series[i] - series[i-1] for i in range(1, len(series))]
>>> min_sum_subsequence(returns)
-5
```

You have to add code to keep track of the index of the start and finish.

Comment: Great link to an explanation about maximum sum contiguous sequence!  You also described the problem set much more accurately and succinctly than I did.

Answer (score 1):

Its always best to print all the values and check out the results.

The problem with your code is when you write p[i]> p[high] you update the value of newhigh but the value of high is not changing.

Just write it as p[i] > p[newhigh] and check out if its giving the correct results. I have'nt checked if it will give the correct output. Do that on your own.

Though you can always use the shortened versions mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows for much shorter code:

```
l = [300,301,303,299,300,298,301,305]

max([(l[i] - l[j], i, j) for i in range(len(l)) for j in range(i, len(l))], key=lambda x:x[0])

(5, 2, 5)
```

This can maybe be shortened, but it's a good starting point.
Also, as others said, please use [homework] tag if appropriate.
Edit: this answers (drop, begin, end).

Comment: StackOverflow allows for much nicer code formating ;) Use the 101010 button in the answer edition menu to highlight code properly (see the other answers on this page for an example of the result). Cheers!

Comment: You have nested list comprehension _and_ `lambda` _and_ modified `max` - not quite readable.

Comment: The original answer asked for correctness, not for readability. Anyway, this is a one-liner. One can spend a couple lines of comments to help readability :)

Answer (score 0):

Having copy-pasted your code and indented it, you're nearly there. Where you test:

```
if p[i] >= p[high]:
```

You're not considering that p[i] might be >= p[high], but less than p[newhigh].

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the largest non-monotonically decreasing sequence.  There is a similar question for monotonically in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310043/find-the-length-of-the-largest-increasing-sequence).  Lots of ways to approach this problem.  Here is a recursive approach.

```
def biggest_drop(sequence):
    seq_min, seq_max = min(sequence), max(sequence)
    imin, imax = sequence.index(seq_min), sequence.index(seq_max)
    if imin == imax:
        return None
    if imin < imax:
        # split the sequence and look for local drops
        drop_a = biggest_drop(sequence[:imax])
        drop_b = biggest_drop(sequence[imax:])
        if drop_a is None or drop_b is None:
            if drop_a:
                return drop_a
            return drop_b
        value_a = drop_a[0] - drop_a[-1] 
        value_b = drop_b[0] - drop_b[-1]
        if value_a > value_b:
            return drop_a
        else:
            return drop_b
    return sequence[imax:imin+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
start_=stop_=None
min_=0
for start in range(len(li)-1):
    for stop in range(start+1, len(li)):
        tmp= li[stop]-li[start]
        if tmp<min_:
            min_=tmp
            start_=start
            stop_=stop
print min_
print (start_, stop_)
```

It works for your sample.

Answer (score 0):

There's a faster way to compute `mins` than this example, but this is concise and readable:

```
>>> data = [300, 301, 303, 299, 300, 298, 301, 305]
>>> mins = [min(data[i:]) for (i, _) in enumerate(data)]
>>> mins
[298, 298, 298, 298, 298, 298, 301, 305]
>>> drops = [ d - m for (d, m) in zip(data, mins)]
>>> drops
[2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [ (i, data[i] - drop) for (i, drop) in enumerate(drops) if drop == max(drops) ]
[(2, 298)]
```

Knowing that the start of the period is 2 and the low point is 298, the end of the period is:

```
>>> [ i for (i, x) in enumerate(data) if i > 2 and x == 298]
[5]
```